# Unable to trigger Broadcast SMS receiver in MIUI Rom

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

I have tested my code on Emulator as well as CM9 ROM. Everything works fine. But when I run my app on MIUI v3.6.28 Android Version 4.1.2 it doesn't trigger the SMS receiver.

I searched around on StackOverflow but couldnt find suitable answer except one mentioning about Phone manufacturers implementing internal classes themselves to avoid such behaviour. And MIUI being Xiami ROM maybe that is true. But then how would Go SMS and Handcent SMS work on these devices ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://miuiandroid.com/community/threads/sms-notification-not-working.16464/

This might solve the problem.  I did not check it since I have moved to cm again for testing . but seems to solve exactly what I need. And description makes sense.

Miui takes preference and takes away the SMS before any other app can receive it.

Comment: Please post the solution, as link provided is dead

Comment: https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://miuiandroid.com/community/threads/sms-notification-not-working.16464/

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20130906231130/http://miuiandroid.com/community/threads/sms-notification-not-working.16464/

Comment: The original link is dead. But the solution seems to be some kind of "Priority Setting toggle" in MIUI stock messaging app. I don't think it exist anymore in latest roms

Answer (score 2):

In Xiaomi devices, you just have to add your app to Autostart list, to do so, follow these simple steps given below:

1. Open **Security** app on your phone.
2. Tap on **Permissions**, it'll show youtwo options: Autostart and Permissions.
3. Tap on **Autostart**, it'll show you list of apps with on or off toggle
   buttons.
4. Turn on toggle of your app, you're done!

> Note : When ran through your app via USB permissions is denied by
>   default for READ_SMS. You need to enable permission in Permission tab
>   of Security app for your app.